# magento code performance issue

Tags: performance

I have a magento website , this website has two different themes. All db and products are the same but my new theme seems much slower to load the product details page. My new theme takes twice the time as compared to the old one.

How can I fix this issue I want to analyse which part takes more time is there a way to analyse using break points like which part(s) are more complex and consumes more time?

Please guide me how to do it

1: As theme is just different, all other factors are the same
2: I want to know which part takes time, I tried commenting out whole view.phtml but still there was a load issue there, how can I break and debug it to find out the exact issue?

Comment: currently  your site 151 process executed on homepage.

Comment: http://www.gxjansen.com/101-ways-to-speed-up-your-magento-e-commerce-website/

Comment: currently your site 151 process executed on homepage ??